# Why does this for loop with a floating-point increment end one step early?

Tags: c, for-loop, floating-point

To practise using a for loop, I have been asked by my lecturer to create a program which lists all the numbers from **-9.9** to **-9.7** in ascending order in increments of **0.005**.

I wrote the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

double list;

for (list = -9.9; list <= -9.7; list += 0.005){
printf("%f \n",list);
}

return 0;
}
```

However, the last number which is printed on my console is **-9.705000**. Why is this the case? Shouldn't the last number to be printed be **-9.7** since the condition I used in my for loop is ***list < = 9.7*** ?

[The numbers displayed on my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Laij0.jpg)

Comment: You may use integers instead. Multiply everything by let's say `1000` . Divide by `1000` when you're about to print the values.

Comment: Running your code in the debugger shows that the final value of `list` that breaks the loop is `-8.7999999999998284`. Floating point arithmetic cannot represent all real numbers accurately.

Comment: After having read the link, could my question please be reopened as I would like to know how write a for loop which completes the task posed by my lecturer despite the limitations of floating point numbers.

Comment: @user22752014 You could use integers as Jardel suggested. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/r9e5Es8b9)

Comment: @pmacfarlane the value that exceeded the loop termination (using `"%.16f"`) was `-9.6999999999999691` which is > `-9.7`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not when I commented. The question has been edited.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I see the question originally said "-8.8", sorry. I suppose their assignment was changed :)